# When using cordova-plugin-file on iOS, how do I save a file into the apps cloud container?

Tags: ios, containers, cordova-plugin-file

The docs for cordova-plugin-file are a little ambiguous when it comes to iOS.  I have set up an iCloud container sandboxed within my app.  But it is not clear from the cordova-plugin-file docs which directory to use to put files into the sandboxed cloud container.

I have tried cordova.file.syncedDataDirectory and cordova.file.documentsDirectory.

I know both of these directories work, I can save and retrieve files from them within my app, but I do not know if any of them actually relate to the icloud container in my app.

Any help would be appreciated.